# Layout Issue Xcode - Search Bar auto move

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisearchbar

i have this problem and don't know how to fix it at all

In mainstoryboard, i had set auto top layout for Top Bar was 20
First, my search bar (Top Bar) has y-position is 84 but look like this, i it is what i want for all time of my apps

[image]

But then, when i chose search Bar,i use  `func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar)` to show up another Bar, but even the another not showing up, my Search Bar (Top Bar) move down, i look not good at all, but it's y-position now : 20 ??
Here is what it look like

[image]

So, can someone help me about this ?? Thanks alot

Comment: Hai , how do you show the `another bar`? post the code. and when your `search bar` is editing, the `search bar` move down ?

Comment: i just addsubview, and hide it, but i tried, even i didn't do that (add another bar), just click on searchBar, it wend down ?

Answer (score 0):

try this in viewDidLoad method

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7)
{ 
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=YES;
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
}
```